# How to create a channel then find the ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a channel with `message.guild.channels.create`. How do I go about then finding the message id of that channel and sending a message in the newly created channel?

```
message.guild.channels.create(`bug-priority${reportPriority}-${reportStart}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [{
    id: message.author.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
  {
    id: memberRole.id,
    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`guild.channels.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns a promise that resolves to a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). It means you can await the result and that's the newly created channel:

```js
const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`bug-priority${reportPriority}-${reportStart}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
    },

    {
      id: memberRole.id,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
    },
  ],
});

const { id } = channel;
```

Make sure that the parent function is an `async` fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bot.channels.cache.find()` to get the id after creating the channel, like so:

```
let channel = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "name here");
let channelid = channel.id;
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: `create()` is asynchronous. Are you sure the channel will be available by the time Node.js executes  your function?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Correct, I didn't think about that